# How can I check if a user is a bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot and I am using the event `guildMemberAdd` like this:

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member) {

});
```

How can I check if the `member` is a bot or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`member` is of type [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and has a `user` property of type [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), which has a boolean `bot` property to indicate whether or not the user is a bot. So `member.user.bot` will tell you if the added member is a bot.